# Finding PID's of Virtual Machine in openstack

Tags: virtual-machine, pid, openstack

I am working on openstack and I want to monitor the Virtual Machines cpu usage. For that I want to find their PIDs through the parent (central) openstack instance.
I used

ps aux | grep

and I did receive an output. I however want to confirm if this is correct PID. Is their any way I can check this?

Or is their any other way to find the PID's of the virtual machine?

Update.
This command does not work . It gives me a PID which always change. Its not constant.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well libvirt has some interfaces for this.  Here's some python that extracts that data into datastructures for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Modules
import subprocess
import traceback
import commands
import signal
import time
import sys
import re
import os
import getopt
import pprint



try:
    import libvirt
except:
    print "no libvirt detected"
    sys.exit(0)
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

global instances
global virt_conn
global tick
global virt_exist

def virtstats():
    global virt_exist
    global virt_conn
    global instances
    cpu_stats = []
    if virt_exist == True:
        if virt_conn == None:
            print 'Failed to open connection to the hypervisor'
            virt_exist = False

    if virt_exist == True:

        virt_info = virt_conn.getInfo()
        for x in range(0, virt_info[2]):
            cpu_stats.append(virt_conn.getCPUStats(x,0))
        virt_capabilities = virt_conn.getCapabilities()
        domcpustats = 0
        # domcpustats = virDomain::GetcpuSTATS()
        totmem = 0
        totvcpu = 0
        totcount = 0
        vcpu_stats = []
        for id in virt_conn.listDomainsID():
            dom = virt_conn.lookupByID(id)
            totvcpu += dom.maxVcpus()
            vcpu_stats.append(dom.vcpus())
            totmem += dom.maxMemory()
            totcount += 1

        dom = parseString(virt_capabilities)
        xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('model')[0].toxml()
        xmlData=xmlTag.replace('<model>','').replace('</model>','')
        for info in virt_info:
            print info
        for stat in cpu_stats:
            print "cpu %s" % stat
        for vstat in vcpu_stats:
            print "vcpu:\n"
            pprint.pprint(vstat)
        print "CPU ( %s ) Use - %s vCPUS ( %s logical processors )" % (xmlData, totvcpu, virt_info[2])
        sys.exit(0)



def main():

    try:
        global virt_conn
        global virt_exist
        virt_conn = libvirt.openReadOnly(None)
        virt_exist = True
    except:
        virt_exist = False
        print "OK: not a compute node"
        sys.exit(0)

    virtstats()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now what you get from this in terms of usage is cpu time.

The vcpu blocks are basically in this layout:

> ```
> 1st: vCPU number, starting from 0.
> 2nd: vCPU state.
>     0: offline
>     1: running
>     2: blocked on resource
> 3rd: CPU time used in nanoseconds
> 4th: real CPU number
> ```

The CPU blocks are obvious once you realize that's what's goin down in libvirt.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear before. It not only about cpu usage but many factors of the Virtual Machine and for that I require PID of virtual machine. I want to gather this information by running command from my hypervisor itself so that I receive the statistic data of the VM. And I want to do this using PIDs. Is there any method that can help me to get the PIDs of the virtual machines..

Comment: You will get much more information out of libvirt than you will from a process ID.  In fact, libvirt purposefully doesn't give a method to get the process ID as interacting with the process ID is the wrong way to do anything with libvirt.  

If you are dead set on going down that path though ( and I recommend heavily against doing so ), you will probably want to so a process list identify the qemu / kvm / what have you processes and then distinguish which vm is which by awking the flags and matching against some shared value set in the libvirt domains.

I again caution against this.

Answer (score 1):

By using libvirt, python, lxml, and lsof you can recover the pid if your Virtual Instance (domain) has a display output set. (VNC, Spice, ...)

1. Retrieve display port
2. Retrieve pid from opened display port

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from lxml import etree
import libvirt
from subprocess import check_output

def get_port_from_XML(xml_desc):
    tree = etree.fromstring(xml_desc)
    ports = tree.xpath('//graphics/@port')
    if len(ports):
        return ports[0]
    return None

def get_pid_from_listen_port(port):
    if port is None:
        return ''
    return check_output(['lsof', '-i:%s' % port, '-t']).replace('\n','')

conn = libvirt.openReadOnly('')
if conn is None:
    print 'Failed to open connection to the hypervisor'
    sys.exit(1)

for domain_id in conn.listDomainsID():
    domain_instance = conn.lookupByID(domain_id)
    name = domain_instance.name()
    xml_desc = domain_instance.XMLDesc(0)
    port = get_port_from_XML(xml_desc)
    pid = get_pid_from_listen_port(port)
    print '%s (port:%s) (pid:%s)' % (name, port, pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "79d87652-8c8e-4afa-8c13-32fbcbf98e76" --include=libvirt.xml /path/to/nova/instances -r -A 2 | grep "<name"  | cut -d " " -f 3
```

allows to find "instance-" which can be mapped to ps aux output of "-name" parameter. so you can map openstack instance id to pid.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is using cgroups:

In Ubuntu:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/libvirt/qemu/<machine-name>/tasks
```